# Purpose of return types for methods

Tags: c#, methods, return

I am having issues understanding the syntax of C# Methods - specifically the `"must return something"` error.

I have this method:

```
public static class Connection
{
    public static List<string> getClients()
    {   
        List<string> clients = new List<string>();
        return clients;
    }
}
```

The method is incorrect since I get `invalid expression term "return"`, so I don't exactly know what to do.  Can someone explain me how this public void, etc, works?

Also, why I cant do the following?

```
public getClients()
    {   
        List<string> clients = new List<string>();
        return clients;
    }
```

I get an error saying `method must have a return type`

Comment: Your first code sample shouldn't give that (or any) error message.  Are you sure there isn't something different about your real code?  Does your file include `using System.Collections.Generic;` at the top?

Comment: Can you show us the *exact* code that produces the error: `invalid expression term "return"`

Comment: Acutally the first error was solved sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every method needs to have a return type, or be declared with a void return type.

If you don't want to return anything, you would have a void return type, like below...

```
public void printSomething(string something)
{
  System.out.println(something);
}
```

If you want to return something, you have to declare the return type, like below...

```
public string returnSomething()
{
  string something = "something";
  return something;
}
```

So for your example, if you are returning "`clients`" which is of type `List<string>`, then you need to declare that return type, like below...

```
public List<string> getClients()
{
  List<string> clients = new List<string>();
  return clients;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this will help me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

What you're working with are called *return types*.  When you define a method, you can set a type (such as integer, Bitmap, string, or even a custom class) to be returned as a value.  That way, you can do the following:

```
int number = Average();
```

For a method that does *not* return a value, you can set the **void** keyword to signify that this method performs actions, but does not get a tangible result.  Whereas the `Average()` method above returns an int when it's finished, a void returns nothing.

Additionally, **public** and **static** are keywords are adjectives that describe your method, be it void or not.  Public refers to its privacy (or what sections of code can use it) and static refers to the lifetime and reference of a method.

Answer (score 1):

The first piece of code should work.

If you don't want to return anything from a function, make it return void:

```
public void DoWork() {
    int i = 1 + 1;
} // Don't return anything.
```

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking at all

Comment: " if someone can explain me how this public void, etc, works?"

Comment: Your answer does not describe how it works, it describes when you would want to use void

Comment: I think it's unreasonable to downvote this...  The question was answered sufficiently with an example.  +1

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error saying `method must have a return type` in the second code because you are not returning a list but the return type is not present in the method signature. For a method with no return type you should use `void`.

```
public void method()//void or no return type
{
   //do something
}
```

Your first code is absolutely fine and should work without error